# How to indicate which php version to use in a background process

Tags: php, background-process

I'm running MAMP with PHP 5.5.18 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2014 16:18:57) on Mac OS X 10.10.1.

All is well, except when I issue a background php process from within my PHP script. The process runs fine although my logs tell me a specific extension (mcrypt) is not installed when in fact I know it is. Well, I know it's installed in my 5.5.18 version. So this is leading me to believe the background process might be accessing a different version of php.

Two questions:
1) How can I tell which version of PHP the background process is accessing?
2) Is there a way to force the background process to use a specific version of PHP?

Comment: How do you issue the background-process?

Comment: You probably launch the main script through Apache and the background one through command line. Same version, just different settings.

Comment: What does `php -v` give? And `php -i | grep "PHP Version"` give?

Comment: PHP-FPM and PHP-CLI do not share the same .ini files. That means that (probably) your CLI php.ini doesn't have the mcrypt extension loaded. `php --ini` will tell you which .ini file the CLI loads. Check whether you loaded mcrypt there.

Comment: php --ini returns /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/conf/php.ini

Comment: How do I find the config file for PHP-FPM?

Comment: Is there a way to force the background process to use a specific version of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This question about how to force a background process to use a specific version of php has been answered here: [How to configure PHP to run the same version on the web server as in a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250198/how-to-configure-php-to-run-the-same-version-on-the-web-server-as-in-a-backgroun/27257243#27257243)