# How to configure PHP to run the same version on the web server as in a background process

Tags: php, macos, mamp, background-process

From the command line:

```
php --info
//⇒ PHP Version => 5.5.18
```

From the command line within a background process:

```
exec('php --info>>logs/phpVersion.txt');
//⇒ PHP Version => 5.5.14
```

I want the background process to run version 5.5.18 (or the same version as the web server). Where is that configured?

Answer (score 2):

You must reinstall 5.5.18 to replace 5.5.14. It's not a configuration file, there are two instances of PHP.

If you specify on OS, I will update this answer with further instruction. (Or just Google it)

Comment: I'm running MAMP, OS X 10.10.1

Comment: Actually, either version is fine. I just need both modes to access the same version. I'm not sure how to do that with MAMP.

Comment: @user1486941 MAMP is maintaining its own version of PHP; 5.5.14 is installed on your Mac.

Comment: Right. That's the issue. How do I get MAMP to see a background process?

Comment: That post is to get MAMP to see other php versions installed in MAMP. It has no impact on Yosemite's installed version. Maybe a better way to ask my question is: "How do I get MAMP to see the background process before Yosemite calls its installed version?"

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for getting the MAMP version of PHP to run a background process instead of your system's version of php, is to simply call your MAMP version, right there in the exec() function. So for me, that call looks something like this:

exec('/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.18/bin/php myscript.php &');